# CodeIgniter: How to use WHERE clause and OR clause

Tags: mysql, select, codeigniter, where-clause

I am using the following code to select from a MySQL database with a Code Igniter webapp:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable',array('id'=>10));
```

This works great! But I want to write the following MySQL statement using the CI library?

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id`='10' OR `field`='value'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: though i am only 3 years late but from which table will it get it? how to specify the table

Comment: Though I am 3/4 of a month late, you still execute the following after your where clauses are defined... 

$this->db->get("tbl_name");

Comment: `$where = '(name="Joe" AND status="boss" OR status="active")';`  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9941814/594235

Answer (score 33):

You can use or_where() for that - example from the CI docs:

```
$this->db->where('name !=', $name);

$this->db->or_where('id >', $id); 

// Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' OR id > 50
```

Comment: according to the documentation or_where is deprecated.  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I believe you might have misread that.  It seems to me to be saying that the old method, orwhere(), has been deprecated in favor of the new method or_where().

Comment: Thanks for clarify this! big help even 4 years later!

Answer (score 13):

You can use this :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$this->db->where(name,'Joe');
$bind = array('boss', 'active');
$this->db->where_in('status', $bind);
```

Comment: How do I get the results ?

Comment: Where are the results stored ?

Answer (score 7):

Active record method `or_where` is to be used:

```
$this->db->select("*")
->from("table_name")
->where("first", $first)
->or_where("second", $second);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

$this->db->where($where);
```

Though I am 3/4 of a month late, you still execute the following after your where clauses are defined... `$this->db->get("tbl_name");`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me :

```
  $where = '';
   /* $this->db->like('ust.title',$query_data['search'])
        ->or_like('usr.f_name',$query_data['search'])
        ->or_like('usr.l_name',$query_data['search']);*/
        $where .= "(ust.title like '%".$query_data['search']."%'";
        $where .= " or usr.f_name like '%".$query_data['search']."%'";
        $where .= "or usr.l_name like '%".$query_data['search']."%')";
        $this->db->where($where);



$datas = $this->db->join(TBL_USERS.' AS usr','ust.user_id=usr.id')
            ->where_in('ust.id', $blog_list) 
            ->select('ust.*,usr.f_name as f_name,usr.email as email,usr.avatar as avatar, usr.sex as sex')
            ->get_where(TBL_GURU_BLOG.' AS ust',[
                'ust.deleted_at'     =>  NULL,
                'ust.status'     =>  1,
            ]);
```

I have to do this to create a query like this :

```
SELECT `ust`.*, `usr`.`f_name` as `f_name`, `usr`.`email` as `email`, `usr`.`avatar` as `avatar`, `usr`.`sex` as `sex` FROM `blog` AS `ust` JOIN `users` AS `usr` ON `ust`.`user_id`=`usr`.`id` WHERE (`ust`.`title` LIKE '%mer%' ESCAPE '!' OR  `usr`.`f_name` LIKE '%lok%' ESCAPE '!' OR  `usr`.`l_name` LIKE '%mer%' ESCAPE '!') AND `ust`.`id` IN('36', '37', '38') AND `ust`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `ust`.`status` = 1 ;
```