# Codeigniter select query with AND and OR condition

Tags: codeigniter

I want a Codeigniter select query from a table with three conditions in .

```
1. wrk_fld_exc = 140
2. wrk_cs_sts = Open
3. wrk_dlvrd_sts = Delivered OR wrk_cl_sts = Success
```

The third condition is an AND condition contains OR condition.
First and second is And condition.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can code it like this:

```
       $this->db->where('wrk_fld_exc',140);
       $this->db->where('wrk_cs_sts','open');
       $where = '(wrk_dlvrd_sts="open" or wrk_cl_sts = "Success")';
       $this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: thanx its work for me and i modified it like                                    $city=$params['search']['city'];                                                                                      $like = "(location like '%$city%' or address like '%$city%' or city like '%$city%')";
$this->db->where($like);

Comment: How to pass with a variable instead typing 140?

Answer (score 7):

codeigniter uses its own syntax for OR claus in query

```
$this->db->or_where('wrk_cl_sts','Success');
```

to use AND in where clause use `$this->db->where('');` twice

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
 $this->db->where('wrk_fld_exc',140);
 $this->db->where('wrk_cs_sts','open');
 $this->db->where('wrk_dlvrd_sts ','Delivered');
 $this->db->or_where('wrk_cl_sts','Success');
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to add some info for `Codeigniter 3.1.11`:

There is a `Query grouping` in `Query Builder Class`

So Ben Answer will be like this:

```
public function some_function()
    {
        $this->db->where("wrk_fld_exc",140);
        $this->db->where("wrk_cs_sts","Open");
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->where("wrk_dlvrd_sts","Delivered");
        $this->db->or_where("wrk_cl_sts","Success");
        $this->db->group_end();
        return $this->db->get("some_table");
    }
```

After check with:

```
        echo $this->db->last_query();
```

It will produce SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `wrk_fld_exc` = 140 AND `wrk_cs_sts` = 'Open' AND ( `wrk_dlvrd_sts` = 'Delivered' OR `wrk_cl_sts` = 'Success' )
```

Further Read:
[Codeigniter Manual Book](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db->where('wrk_fld_exc',140);

 $this->db->where('wrk_cs_sts','open');

 $where = '(wrk_dlvrd_sts="open" or wrk_cl_sts = "Success")';

 $this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("table_name");
    if($condition1 != ''){
        $this->db->where('wrk_fld_exc', 140);
    }
    if($condition2 != ''){
        $this->db->where('wrk_cs_sts ', open);
    }
    //You can limit the results
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
```

This is the basic structure of the query you can implement in this way in codeigniter. You can add conditions if you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where ('attribute',$data['attribute']);
$this->db->or_where ('attribute',$data['attribute']);
$this->db->and_where ('attribute',$data['attribute']);
```

Comment: There is no and_where in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$city=$params['search']['city']; 
$like = "(location like '%$city%' or address like '%$city%' or city like '%$city%')"; 
$this->db->where($like);
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Recommend you to add some details, like how this fixes the problem.