# Where clause based multiple dynamic values, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

The drop down box is dynamically populated based on what the customer the user has been assigned to. The problem is that when I want to search for customers that the user is assigned to (if they choose the option of viewing `All` customers), I would have to do a query like:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM LotDispDashBoardDB.disp_dummy where (customer = 'DL1' or customer = 'BC1') and stage like 'T%' and lot_status like 'close%';
```

I don't want to do

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM LotDispDashBoardDB.disp_dummy where stage like 'T%' and lot_status like 'close%';
```

because I want users to be able to see their own assigned customers only, I do not want them to see all the available customers.

The dropdown box has only one fixed value which is `All`, the rest of it are the individual customer names. If the user selects `All` means he wants to view `All` his assigned customers. In the controller below, if he selects all I would get the `$all_customer` array. If not I would just get the customer selected.

In the model to know if it's all or not I detect whether the value received is an array or not. If it's an array, I iterate through it an use CodeIgniter's active record `$this->db->or_where('customer', $customer);` to do the query. The **MAIN PROBLEM** is the query. As stated before I am try to do like Query 1. **How can I put the brackets and dynamically write the `where` clause?**

Controller:

```
public function load_lot_table()
{
    // Get customers from session
    $customer_session = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['customers'];

    foreach($customer_session as $cust_object)
    {
        $all_customer[] = $cust_object->customer;
    }

    // Get form values
    if($this->input->get())
    {
        $selected_customer = $this->input->get('cust_drop_down');
        $stage = $this->input->get('area_drop_down');
        $lot_status = $this->input->get('status_drop_down');
        $search_lot = ltrim( $this->input->get('search_lot') );

        if($selected_customer == 'all')
        {
            $customer = $all_customer;
        }
        else
        {
            $customer = $selected_customer;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Default values when page is loaded because form is not submitted yet
        $customer = $all_customer;
        $stage = 'all';
        $lot_status = 'all';
        $search_lot = '';
    }

    // Keys are the column names
    $search = array(
    'customer' => $customer,
    'stage' => $stage,
    'lot_status' => $lot_status,
    'search_lot' => $search_lot
    );

    // Paginate retrieved lots
    $results = $this->paginate_create_table($search);

    /*** other codes ***/

}

private function paginate_create_table($search = null)
{
    if( is_array( $search['customer'] ) )
    {
        $customer = 'all';
    }
    else
    {
        $customer = $search['customer'];
    }

    // Set pagination configuration
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/Home/on_hold_lot";
    $config['suffix'] = '?cust_drop_down='.$customer.'&area_drop_down='.$search['stage'].'&status_drop_down='.$search['lot_status'].'&search_lot='.$search['search_lot'];
    $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].$config['suffix'];
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->home_model->fetch_lots('rows', $search);
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    /*** Other codes ****/
}
```

Model:

```
public function fetch_lots($return, $search = null, $limit = null, $start = 0)
{
    if($limit != null)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    }

    if($search != null)
    {
        if( $search['customer'] != 'all' && !is_array( $search['customer'] ) )
        {
            $this->db->where('customer', $search['customer']);
        }
        elseif( is_array( $search['customer'] ) )
        {
            foreach($search['customer'] as $customer)
            {
                $this->db->or_where('customer', $customer);
            }
        }

        if($search['stage'] != 'all')
        {
            $this->db->like('stage', $search['stage'], 'after');
        }

        if($search['lot_status'] != 'all')
        {
            $this->db->like('lot_status', $search['lot_status'], 'after');
        }

        if($search['search_lot'] != '')
        {
            $this->db->where('utac_lot', $search['search_lot']);
        }
    }
    /*** Other codes ***/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter allows you to [pass a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941814/144194) to `$this->db->where()`

Example:

```
$where = "(this = $that)";
$this->db->where($where);
```

As you loop through `$search['customer']`, you could build a string to use as your `where` query.

```
if( $search['customer'] != 'all' && !is_array( $search['customer'] ) )
    {
        $this->db->where('customer', $search['customer']);
    }
    elseif( is_array( $search['customer'] ) )
    {
        for($i = 0, $i <= count($search['customer'], $i++)
        {
            // Use a FOR instead of FOREACH so we can count the loops.
            // 'WHERE' will be used on the first loop,
            // subsequent loops use 'OR'.
            if($i == 0) 
            {
                $where = "( WHERE customer = $search['customer'][$i] ";
            } else {
                $where .= " OR customer` = $search['customer'][$i] ";
            }
            if($i == count($search['customer']))
            {
                $where .= " ) ";
            }
        }
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
//... etc..
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think I've found an easier solution. Will post it, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that I came up with.

```
// If user selects a customer
if( $search['customer'] != 'all' && !is_array( $search['customer'] ) )
{
    $this->db->where('customer', $search['customer']);
}
// If user selects ALL
elseif( is_array( $search['customer'] ) )
{
    foreach($search['customer'] as $customer)
    {
        $all_customer[] = "customer = '$customer'";
    }

    // Example query would form: (customer = 'ABC' OR customer = 'BCD')
    $where_customer = "(";
    $where_customer .= implode(' OR ', $all_customer);
    $where_customer .= ")";

    $this->db->where($where_customer);
}
```