# Using group_start with codeigniter. Need OR instead of AND

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeiginter and basically I need `OR ()` instead of `AND ()` when using `group_start()`. Is this possible?

What I need to produce is

```
WHERE (u.location LIKE '%?%' OR (u.long BETWEEN ? AND ? AND u.lat BETWEEN ? AND ?)) AND u.active=1
```

What I'm currently doing

```
$this->db->group_start()
->like('u.location',$selector['text']);
if(isset($geo)){
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where('u.long >',$geo->long)
    ->where('u.long <',$geo->longmax)
    ->where('u.lat >',$geo->lat)
    ->where('u.lat <',$geo->latmax)
    ->group_end();
}
$this->db->group_end();
```

What this produces

```
WHERE ( `u`.`location` LIKE '%?%' ESCAPE '!' AND ( `u`.`lat` < ? AND `u`.`lat` > ? AND `u`.`long` < ? AND `u`.`long` > ? ) )
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941566/codeigniter-select-query-with-and-and-or-condition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it!

```
or_group_start();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
$this->db->where('meeting_created_by','1');
  $this->db->join('tbl_meeting_invite','invite_meeting_id=meeting_id','left');
  $this->db->where('meeting_created_by','1');
  $this->db->where('meeting_created_by','1');
  $this->db->where('invite_user_id !=','');
  $this->db->group_start();
  $this->db->or_where('invite_user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
  $this->db->group_end();
  $this->db->group_by('invite_meeting_id');
  $data['invited_list']=$this->db->get('tbl_meeting');
```